# SharePoint, to GAC, or not to GAC?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, assemblies, gac, bin-folder

It's clear from these questions

[When and when-not to install into the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498361/when-and-when-not-to-install-into-the-gac)
[What are the advantages and disadvantages of using the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-the-gac)
[To GAC, or not to GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561937/to-gac-or-not-to-gac)

that it is not recommended to deploy assemblies to GAC as explained.
So, I'm wondering why is the default of SharePoint solutions built using Visual Studio or WSP Builder is to deploy assemblies to GAC?

Comment: Those questions are very generic; SharePoint imposes its own set of advantages and disadvantages. [MSDN SharePoint articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms521365(v=office.12).aspx) usually favor the GAC.

Comment: @bzlm: from link "To keep the procedure simple, this topic assumes that you want to place the assembly in the bin directory." I again wonder which deployment approach should we consider while solution deployment. We are looking for a standard/recommended approach to follow.

Comment: read the rest of the article as well, especially the pros and cons of bin and GAC. :) It's not a choice of style; just like [Adam says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084551/sharepoint-to-gac-or-not-to-gac/7084632#7084632) it's a choice of intended use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various sharepoint components (besides just the site) won't be able to find it in the bin folder.
See this other post for more details.

[Does a SharePoint EventReceiver have to be installed in the GAC, and if so do all dependent assemblies have to as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621468/does-a-sharepoint-eventreceiver-have-to-be-installed-in-the-gac-and-if-so-do-all)